# Para que serve o In[]: e out[]:?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Há algum tempo estou escrevendo alguns scripts básicos com o Python, em alguns tutoriais as vezes me deparo com `In []:` e `Out[]`, normalmente aparecem ao testa igualdade de valores. Abaixo um pequeno exemplo.

```
In [24]: a = float("Nan")

In [25]: b = a

In [26]: b is a
Out[26]: True

In [27]: b == a
Out[27]: False

In [28]: a == a
Out[28]: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente os tutoriais que vocês está vendo estão sendo programados e executados em ambientes como o **Jupyter Notebook**. 
O JN é um ambiente virtual voltado à educação de códigos já que com ele fica mais fácil visualmente ensinar as estruturas de código, pelo menos em comparação com um output convencional de uma IDE.

É bastante comum em tutorias de YouTube, principalmente aqueles dos Estados Unidos, de acordo com minha experiência.

Assim, os `In` e '`Out`'s que você vê nada mais é do que uma linha de entrada de código (`In`) e a linha de saída (`Out`). Se você executar em uma IDE convencional, como o Pycharm, vai ver que não tem diferença nenhuma nos códigos, sintaxes e valores de entrada/saída.

Claro que tem o JN pode ter uma aplicação bem mais profunda, mas geralmente vejo ele sendo usado com este propósito de plataforma para exibição facilitada de código. [Mais infos aqui](https://jupyter.org/)

Answer (score 7):

O `In[]:` é como alguns ambientes interativos colocam o prompt para você digitar uma expressão em Python. Ele fica no lugar do `>>>`, que você vê quando chama "Python" ou no "idle".

Já o `Out[]` é só um prefixo para o valor de retorno de uma expressão. São usados no Jupyter Notebook, mas também no "ipython" que pode ser usado no shell (cmd no windows), no lugar do Python normal.

Na prática, se for um exemplo de elementos interativos, é só você digitar tudo que vem depois do `In[]:` depois do `>>>` do seu Python.

Além disso eu recomendo o uso do [iPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), sem o notebook mesmo, no lugar do ambiente interativo padrão (o executável de Python que roda por dentro é o mesmíssimo - você só ganha algumas funcionalidades a mais - em particular, pode editar de forma interativa blocos de código, que o ambiente padrao te obriga a editar linha a linha). Basta digitar `pip install ipython` e chamar "ipython" em vez de "python3".

Comment: Outra vantagem do iPython comparado ao shell normal é que a presença/ausência do `Out[]` deixa claro quando um valor é retornado e quando é printado, o que tende a confundir bastante para quem está iniciando.